# Nested if statements jump over other ifs

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I'm an old fart and this is my first post, so please be kind.  I am working in a proprietary language based on basic on a measuring machine.  I delibritly set the first two checks to fail for testing purposes.  The first set of ifs for size X works great.  When the code is run and it gets to Size_Y, if the operator picks "no I don't want to remeasure" (returning a 7) the code jumps all the way to the last end if.  I suspect I have improperly nested my Ifthens, but I can't see it.

```
Private Sub CheckSpec

'give operator a message if the measure is out of spec

StartAgain:

If Size_X <= 3.125 OR Size_X >= 3.125 then 'actual spec
    'Warn that measure is not in spec and ask for remeasure

    BoxPick=Msgbox( "Measurement in Zone " & Zone & " for Die Size in X is not in spec.  Do you want to measure it again?" , 4 , "Measurment NOT Within Tolerance" ) 
    If BoxPick = 6 THEN 'if operator wants to remeasure, measure again and start checks over
        Call Measure_Die
        GoTo StartAgain
    ElseIF BoxPick <> 7 Then 'If value returned is NOT 6 or 7, throw error
        OperatorMsg "An error has occured.  Contact the tool owner"
        Call Unload
    ElseIF BoxPick = 7 Then 'If operator chooses not to remeasure then keep going
    Else
    End If


Elseif Size_Y <= 1.925 OR Size_Y >= 1.925 then
    'Warn that measure is not in spec and ask for remeasure

    BoxPick=Msgbox( "Measurement in Zone " & Zone & " for Die Size in X is not in spec.  Do you want to measure it again?" , 4 , "Measurment NOT Within Tolerance" ) 
    If BoxPick = 6 THEN 'if operator wants to remeasure, measure again and start checks over
        Call Measure_Die
        GoTo StartAgain
    ElseIF BoxPick <> 7 Then 'If value returned is NOT 6 or 7, throw error
        OperatorMsg "An error has occured.  Contact the tool owner"
        Call Unload
    ElseIF BoxPick = 7 Then 'If operator chooses not to remeasure keep going
    Else
    End If


Elseif Centration_X <= 0.175 OR Centration_X >= 0.225 then

    'Warn that measure is not in spec and ask for remeasure
    BoxPick=Msgbox( "Measurement in Zone " & Zone & " for Die Size in X is not in spec.  Do you want to measure it again?" , 4 , "Measurment NOT Within Tolerance" ) 
    If BoxPick = 6 THEN 'if operator wants to remeasure, measure again and start checks over
        Call Measure_Die
        GoTo StartAgain
    ElseIF BoxPick <> 7 Then 'If value returned is NOT 6 or 7, throw error
        OperatorMsg "An error has occured.  Contact the tool owner"
        Call Unload
    ElseIF BoxPick = 7 Then 'If operator chooses not to remeasure keep going
    Else
    End If


Elseif Centration_Y <= 0.95 OR Centration_Y >= 1.0 then

    'Warn that measure is not in spec and ask for remeasure
    BoxPick=Msgbox( "Measurement in Zone " & Zone & " for Die Size in X is not in spec.  Do you want to measure it again?" , 4 , "Measurment NOT Within Tolerance" ) 
    If BoxPick = 6 THEN 'if operator wants to remeasure, measure again and start checks over
        Call Measure_Die
        GoTo StartAgain
    ElseIF BoxPick <> 7 Then 'If value returned is NOT 6 or 7, throw error
        OperatorMsg "An error has occured.  Contact the tool owner"
        Call Unload
    ElseIF BoxPick = 7 Then 'If operator chooses not to remeasure keep going
    Else
    End If
Else

End If
Print #1, Column & "," & Row & "," & Level & "," &  Zone & "," & Size_X & "," & Size_Y & "," & Centration_X & "," & Centration_Y & "," & RightNow

End Sub 'CheckSpec
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I formatted that a bit. It actually looks a lot like Visual Basic to me...

Answer (score 1):

When you have an expression like

```
If (2 + 2 == 4) then
     do something
ElseIf (3 + 3 == 6) then
     code never gets here, even though it is true
End If
```

Probably the quickest change is to change your major ElseIf statements to be their own If block

from:

```
Elseif Size_Y <= 1.925 OR Size_Y >= 1.925 then
```

to:

```
End If 'Size_X block check end
If Size_Y <= 1.925 OR Size_Y >= 1.925 then
```

and then from:

```
Elseif Centration_Y <= 0.95 OR Centration_Y >= 1.0 then
```

to:

```
End If 'Size Y block end
If Centration_Y <= 0.95 OR Centration_Y >= 1.0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter another part of the ELSEIF block if you are already in one of the "true" parts of the IF block.  You are already inside the block and the only place left to go is that last END-IF.

Also, in most cases, `GOTO` isn't the best way to do things.

Consider something like this, refactor as needed:

```
Public Enum MeasureResponse
  StartOver
  KeepGoing
  UnloadApp
End Enum

Private Function CheckTolerance(ByVal measureValue As Decimal, ByVal lowTolerance As Decimal, ByVal highTolerance As Decimal) As MeasureResponse
  Dim result As MeasureResponse = MeasureResponse.KeepGoing

  If measureValue <= lowTolerance Or measureValue >= highTolerance Then
    Select Case MessageBox.Show("Measurement in Zone Z for Die Size in X is not in spec.  Do you want to measure it again?", "Measurement NOT Within Tolerance", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
      Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        Call Measure_Die()
        result = MeasureResponse.StartOver
      Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        result = MeasureResponse.UnloadApp
    End Select
  End If

  Return result
End Function
```

Then your CheckSpec function could look something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckSpec()
  For i As Integer = 1 To 4
    Dim checkItem As Decimal = Choose(i, size_X, size_Y, centration_X, centration_Y)
    Dim lowTolerance As Decimal = Choose(i, 3.125, 1.925, 0.175, 0.95)
    Dim highTolerance As Decimal = Choose(i, 3.125, 1.925, 0.225, 1.0)

    Select Case CheckTolerance(checkItem, lowTolerance, highTolerance)
      Case MeasureResponse.StartOver
        i = 0
      Case MeasureResponse.UnloadApp
        Exit Sub
    End Select
  Next

  Print #1, Column & "," & Row & "," & Level & "," &  Zone & "," & Size_X & "," & Size_Y & "," & Centration_X & "," & Centration_Y & "," & RightNow
End Sub
```

This is in VB.Net, but it should be translatable to VB6 or whatever this Basic language is that you are using.

The example tolerances you are using don't make sense either.  `Size_X <= 3.125 OR Size_X >= 3.125` is going to be true every time.  I assume that was for testing purposes.